# How to GROUP BY and count by two columns optimally?

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I want to do data counting on a large table that has two columns with the same values. But in the best possible way

I have a product association table and I want to count how many times the products was associated with another, I want to know which ones were the most associated however my table is too large, I wonder if there is an optimized solution for this

MY TABLE:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user_association_data_2019_02;
+----+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | product_id | association | last_modified       | user_id |
+----+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
|  6 |       1096 | 1355        | 2019-02-04 11:42:07 |    2940 |
| 17 |       1096 | 1758        | 2019-02-04 11:54:10 |    2940 |
| 19 |       1355 | 1758        | 2019-02-04 11:54:15 |    2940 |
| 24 |       1096 | 1758        | 2019-02-04 11:55:31 |    2940 |
| 37 |       1355 | 1758        | 2019-02-04 11:58:54 |    2940 |
| 53 |       1096 | 463         | 2019-02-04 16:38:49 |    2940 |
| 56 |       1758 | 560         | 2019-02-05 10:11:43 |    2940 |
| 57 |       1096 | 560         | 2019-02-05 10:11:45 |    2940 |
| 65 |       1096 | 560         | 2019-02-05 11:10:13 |    2940 |
| 70 |       1758 | 560         | 2019-02-05 12:11:50 |    2940 |
| 74 |       1758 | 560         | 2019-02-05 12:13:27 |    2940 |
| 75 |       1207 | 560         | 2019-02-05 12:13:30 |    2940 |
| 77 |       1096 | 560         | 2019-02-05 12:14:17 |    2940 |
| 79 |       1207 | 1355        | 2019-02-05 14:04:17 |    2940 |
| 81 |       1355 | 560         | 2019-02-06 14:17:25 |    2940 |
| 82 |       1096 | 560         | 2019-02-06 14:17:26 |    2940 |
```

This solve my count

```
mysql> SELECT product_id, association, count(*) as total FROM user_association_data_2019_02 GROUP BY product_id, association;
+------------+-------------+-------+
| product_id | association | total |
+------------+-------------+-------+
|       1096 | 1355        |     1 |
|       1096 | 1758        |     2 |
|       1096 | 463         |     1 |
|       1096 | 560         |     4 |
|       1207 | 1355        |     1 |
|       1207 | 560         |     1 |
|       1355 | 1758        |     2 |
|       1355 | 560         |     1 |
|       1758 | 560         |     3 |
+------------+-------------+-------+
```

But I do not think this is optimized, how to optimize this count?

Comment: When i read this `user_association_data_2019_02` it's clear you have a normalisation problem... The general optimization process involves creating indexes it means you need the index `user_association_data_2019_02 (product_id, association)` to optimize. Then it could execute into using a covering index (all data comes from index data) if MySQL uses the index that is.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no other way to rewrite your query. But you can improve the performance by adding indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD INDEX ix_productid_association (product_id, association);
```

Comment: I couln't understand the use case of index here. The query needs to make aggregation for whole table.

Comment: it is usually faster to fetch the data from an index, and it is already sorted so grouping is faster.

Comment: My query will not have WHERE but I will need to add an ORDER BY to get the top most associated products

```SELECT product_id, association, count (*) as total FROM user_association_data_2019_02 GROUP BY product_id, association ORDER BY total DESC;```

Comment: "My query will not have WHERE " @MateusFelipe Simonare give you a wrong idea in his (deleted) answer that indexes don't work without using a WHERE clause in the query.. Indexes can work without WHERE clause in MySQL so you can forget Simonare 's answer..

Comment: Unfortunately the index will not make `order by count(*)` faster but group by and finding count(*) would be fast.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Understood! Thanks for the help, I'll try

Comment: @SalmanA "finding count(*) would be fast" - Not really "fast" - but might be OK. It still needs a full index scan.